# Remote CMD Login

Tags: windows, command-line, remote-control

I need a VNC/SSH/something server that will let me access command line remotely from a limited account (meaning no services or any install). Just a simple exe that I can run and have it either connect to me or listen for a connection. Preferably it would ask for a user/pass and run the cmd as the user I specify. Is there any such program?

Answer (score 4):

John mentions [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) as being able to run a single executable.  What he doesn't mention is that that executable can be cmd.exe (or powershell or bash or whatever), which will give you a remote shell.

Comment: here's a good overview of how psexec works: http://forum.sysinternals.com/forum_posts.asp?TID=9674&PID=41829#41829  .. but it doesn't mention what it uses for the connection.  (SMB/CIFS? RPC?)

Comment: @JohnT, psexec is *billed* as a *telnet-replacement*, but it isn't telnet, has nothing to do with port 23, and only works if microsoft networking is enabled.

Comment: tho it *does* require a temporary service on the remote machine (which it will install & remove itself).

Comment: I would use psexec but when I run it, it shows a GUI which freezes my console and I have to open up another one to kill it. Is there a switch to disable that GUI message?

Comment: A GUI?!?  The only thing I can think of is that some of those Sysinternals tools require a one-time license agreement.  Other than possibly that, I've never seen any GUI component of psexec.

Comment: The switch /accepteula avoids the EULA popup and automatically accepts it.

Answer (score 0):

Telnet?

[image]

For running a single command over telnet, there is [**psexec**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) from Sysinternals, which is a single executable that doesn't require installation. If you'd like the extra security (recommended) there is [**OpenSSH**](http://sshwindows.sourceforge.net/) for Windows, but that will require an install.

Comment: Telnet is disabled on the server. Is there a third party server that doesn't require being run as a service?

Answer (score 0):

Do-it yourself corner.

There is an open-source on codeproject for two components, server & client. The server is written in java and the client in C++. The server only needs enough permissions to open a socket, as described:

> It first creates a server socket so
>   that clients can connect to it. When a
>   client is connected to the server, it
>   will spawn a new thread using the
>   CommandRunner class to handle the
>   client's request. The main thread will
>   continue to listen for new client.

The server part is here : [Executing commands on a remote machine - Part 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/remoteshell.aspx)
The client part is here : [Executing commands on a remote machine - Part 2](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/remoteshell0002.aspx)

[image]

Comment: The client appears to be written in MFC, judging by the icon =p

Comment: Fixed it. (15 chars)

Comment: I actually coded a reverse-shell for this however I found that for many things it doesn't work (I tried running "runas.exe" from the shell but it doesn't let me enter any input and just closes

Comment: That's probably because as you said it's a limited account.